# Microsoft Report Viewer export to excel

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, rdlc

I have an rdlc report in a VS2005 website. The report renders correctly in the microsoft report viewer and exports to PDF fine. When I try to export it to excel I get the error

> Operation is not vaild due to the current state of the object.

all the stack traces errors begin with

> Microsoft.ReportingServices......

This report has worked previously and all other reports on the site still work as expected and export to excel successfully.

I have tried adding

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="10000" />
</appSettings>
```

to the web.config file

It is a 96 page report but it does not exceed 1000 rows.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could try to fix this error?

**Update**

Converting the website to VS2010 makes no difference.

Comment: If this is an internal report only can you create a new ASP.NET project in debug mode, not publishing it first, in the highest framework you can use (.NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5) and see if the Report Viewer will work when rendering to Excel?  This strikes me as an error with the dll's with the report viewer in an older format.

Comment: All the other reports on the site export to excel, with no problems.

Comment: Can you attempt to recreate the report from scratch as a new rdlc report added to project and test that?  I am wondering then if something in the particular rdlc report has something invalid in it's xml markup or header content.

Comment: What happened if you filter your data and print only a small portion of the 96 pages?